# Stuck in getting distinct records when special characters are in the values

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table data

```
London

Egypt

Newyork

Egypt*

India

China

London+

NewYork*+
```

When I use the following query `select distinct CityName from cityTable`, I am getting 8 records, But I am expecting to have only 5 records as London, Egypt, Newyork, India and china.
But in the above Egypt* and Newyork*+ should not be added to result set, but distinct is considered as a distinct records, can any one help me to get the required result.

I am using Mysql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MySQL group by statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [udf](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp) and replace non-alphanumeric characters.This will leave you just the citynames without special characters.Then you can get distinct above that.